# cPanel Error: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found

Tags: node.js, cpanel

when I try to run script at nodejs setup in cPanel there's some error it says:

returncode: 1
stdout:

> snack-bayi-server@1.0.0 start
> node listener.js
> stderr:
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1282
> return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
> ^

Error: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/omohealt/nodevenv/snackbayi.online/16/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1282:18)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)
at Object. (/home/omohealt/nodevenv/snackbayi.online/16/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12) {
code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}

I set Node.js version 16.20.1

how solve this error?

I set Node.js version 16.20.1 on cPanel

how solve this error?